# Why cant find cookie stored using javascript in the FireFox cookie viewer?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have been trying to set cookie using javascript like this ,

```
<html>
<script>
function set_cookie() {document.cookie="username=John Doe";}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="set_cookie();">set it</a>
</html>
```

i have uploaded the page on webhost and tried clicking the link.

but when i go to

in **FireFox** `Right Click on page > View Page Info > Security > View Cookies`

I cant find cookie there, which is set by above code.

What am i doing wrong. ?

**update**

**it was mistake and was using "Private Browsing" Mode in Firefox.**

Comment: I think, it shows only those cookies which are sent as part of the page request... Try to use the [FireCookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/) plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not using **"Private Browsing"** Mode in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is working. No problem at all. I've tried Firefox and Chrome.

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

Comment: just noticed , i was using private browsing mode .,